# how to set the location of the workbox file generated by workbox-webpack-plugin

Tags: workbox

I replaced sw-precache-webpack-plugin with workbox and followed this guide here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/codelabs/webpack

However, I would like the service-worker.js to load the workbox.js file from the dist folder, instead it tries to load it from the same url as service-worker.js

```
app.use('/dist', serve('./dist', true))
app.use('/service-worker.js', serve('./dist/service-worker.js'))
```

How can I configure the GenerateSW plugin to use the dist folder for the workbox.js file?

This is my config:

```
   new GenerateSW(
      { swDest: 'service-worker.js'
      , cacheId :  cms.config.project.title+'_'+optimist.argv.commit
      , clientsClaim: true
      , skipWaiting: true
      } )
```

And I get the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at....
```

because the location of the workbox-.js is wrong.

Comment: Looking for the same.